# The given key was not present in the dictionary - svn2tfs

Tags: svn, tfs, tortoisesvn, svn2git

This is the usermap.xml file used for usermapping in svn2tfs1.2

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfUserMap xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 

xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <UserMap>
    <SvnUserName>siva</SvnUserName>
    <TfsUserName>sivaramalingam</TfsUserName>
  </UserMap>  
</ArrayOfUserMap>
```

These are the logs when I try to import.

Starting importing...

Connecting to Team Foundation Server... Connected as user(removed the actual name).

Connecting to SubVersion... Connected.

Creating workspace '(workspace details)'...

Project mapped to 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\svn2tfs_635890620955811522_tfs'.

Retrieving files from server...

Workspace ready.

Warning: note field 'SvnRevision' does not exist in the specified team project, information will not be imported.

Warning: note field 'SvnLog' does not exist in the specified team project, information will not be imported.

Warning: note field 'SvnDate' does not exist in the specified team project, information will not be imported.

Ok, let's start!

1 / 156 r2065: **The given key was not present in the dictionary.**

Exited.

Answer (score -1):

Try the solution mentioned in this link: https://svn2tfs.codeplex.com/discussions/354413

> the problem should have been fixed in CS50252, so if you use the
>   latest version from the source code (recompiling the solution), it
>   should work.
>
> Anyway, if you are sure the casing of the usernames is correct and you
>   are sure that all the SVN users are mapped to TFS ones, you should
>   debug and give us more information.